# JQuery datepicker add 1 day to end date minDate

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using this JQuery datepicker code to select a date range.

```
$(function() {
    var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
        from = $("#from").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 3
        }).on("change", function() {
            to.datepicker("option", "minDate", getDate(this));
        }),
        to = $("#to").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 3
        }).on("change", function() {
            from.datepicker("option", "maxDate", getDate(this));
        });

    function getDate(element) {
        var date;
        try {
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(dateFormat, element.value);
        } catch (error) {
            date = null;
        }
        return date;
    }
});
```

I need to add a day on the end date. For example if I choose `12/08/2016` on the start date I want the end date to start at `12/09/2016`.

how can I do this? here is a [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/x2oz8dLa/)

Comment: Can you make a `jsfiddle` or `snippet` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `min-date` option of *to* DatePicker in [**onSelect**](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) event of *from* DatePicker

> Called when the datepicker is selected. The function receives the selected date as text and the datepicker instance as parameters. this refers to the associated input field.

Note: only relevant code add here

```
$('#from').datepicker({
      onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            $('#to').datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(selectedDate).addDays(1));
      }
});

//Method to add days to date
function addDays(date, days) {
  var dat = date;
  dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
  return dat;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmuerho1/6/)